# Does every path in activity diagram have a finish node. Every "fork" branch need to goto a merge?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Does every path in an activity diagram need to have a finish node? A similar question is does every fork branch need to be merged?

I did an activity diagram (below), but it seems wrong. Some branches (from fork) has no finish node (nor end in a merge).

[image]

My idea was the clerk will send shipment packing slip to purchashing, accounting & customer. 2 of which just seem to create/init objects (eg. enter info). They are executed in parallel so I felt I should have a fork?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does every path in an activity diagram need to have a finish node?

Yes.  But there are two kinds of finish node: `ActivityFinal` and `FlowFinal`.  You need to terminate each of the packaging and shipment flows with a `FlowFinal` node.  See section 12.4 in [the spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/Superstructure/PDF/) for details. The symbol is [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/notation/activity-flow-final.png), the [page it's on](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) is a good reference.

> Does every fork branch need to be merged?

No.  But it needs to terminate - hence existence of `FlowFinal` node.

hth.